# Can a Firefox App use a different Useragent?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-os, firefox-browser-api

Is there any way to set the User-agent of an iframe using the [browser-api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Using_the_Browser_API), or even send a SystemXHR request with a different User-agent, from a web-app?

On other systems it's very easy to set a specific UA for a specific WebView but for Firefox apps apparently it isn't possible, or isn't documented yet?

Answer (score -2):

I used a hex editor to modify the binary. As long as you don't change the total number of bytes in Firefox.exe the "new browser" should work. You can also save it as a different file. I made a browser that has some SQL injection code as part of the UA string, and naturally I named the browser Firef**ks. =)

Comment: So a FirefoxOS app that needs to request using another UA would have to modify the OS somehow?

Comment: The FirefoxOS app is digitally signed and cannot be modified as easily. However, if you are using an XHR string, try xhr.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'mybrowser'); This would be an AJAX call, not iframe.